# Unable to re-install ubuntu-desktop, or fix the broken packages required to do so

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dependencies, qt

I don't know how, but somewhere along the way the package ubuntu-desktop got uninstalled from my machine.  I'm starting to notice little breakages all over my system now- I can't upload photos from Shotwell to any online accounts, unity tweak won't start, etc.  I'm on 14.04.2 64 bit with the 3.16.0-31-generic kernel.

I tried re-installing the package in synaptic, was notified that the package is broken, tried the "fix broken packages" option and got the following error message:

`E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies`

I followed that with

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
got a few normal updates and then ran

`sudo apt-get install -f` 
and  got the output

`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.`

I looked back in my terminal to see what the two held packages were, found them and ran

```
sudo apt-get install audacious audacious-plugins
```

And got the output

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 audacious : Depends: libaudcore3 (= 3.6-1~webupd8~trusty3) but it is not going to   be installed
 audacious-plugins : Depends: libaudcore3 (>= 3.6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                          libqt5opengl5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I made sure that the webupd8 ppa was there and tried installing libaudcore3 with the option -f and got the output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libaudcore3 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed    or
                    libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
           Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did the same thing for libqt5gui5, and got the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libqt5gui5 : Depends: libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And so on and so forth...dependency hell, right? I keep coming up with qt packages that are broken. So, I have since updated qt to the latest version available on their website, because the more dependencies I try to fix, the more I see broken qt packages.  The one thing that sticks out to me over and over is this package: qtbase-abi-5-2-1. S, I googled it and found that it's a virtual package provided by libqt5core5a.  One `sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a` later and I get the output

```
libqt5core5a is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Is it time to back up and do a clean install, or is there a way I can fix this mess?  This is what happens when you know just enough to be dangerous to your system, I guess.